# Difference between {x:Static} and {StaticResource} in XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is the difference between `{x:Static}` and `{StaticResource}` in the XAML code for WPF?

For example:

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding Model.IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverseConverter}}">
```

and

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding Model.IsReadOnly, Converter={x:Static BoolInverseConverter}}">
```

And when should I use one or the other?

Comment: `{x:Static}` is for accessing a static property of a type. `{StaticResource}` is for accessing a resource in the `<Resources>` property of a type above it in the visual tree (i.e. in an enclosing element, or in `Application.Resources`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are markup extensions.

[`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) is used to reference a static attribute, which won't change during runtime. This applies to enumerations, constants, `static` properties but also fields.
This means your second code example is wrong as you can't reference a class but only a property. Given that `BoolInverseConverter` is a `static` property of the `Converters` class, the correct code would look like:

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding Model.IsReadOnly, Converter={x:Static Converters.BoolInverseConverter}}">
```

[`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#static-resources) does not mean that the resource is `static` in terms of accessibility but rather in terms of resource lookup. It's a markup extension that instructs the XAML parser to lookup the resource tree to find a predefined instance.
Same does [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#dynamic-resources). The only difference is that `StaticResource` instructs the XAML parser to resolve the reference to a resource at compile time, whereas `DynamicResource` let's the XAML parser create an expression instead, that will be evaluated at run time (deferred). `DynamicResource` therefore resolves the resource at run time.

The following code snippet shows how the resource (the converter) is referenced via resource tree lookup by the XAML parser. Since the XAML markup extension `StaticResource` is used, the lookup is static. This means once the resource was found, it can't be replaced by another instance. And also if the instance is not defined during compile time, the application will crash, throwing a `StaticResourceExtension`. In case the resource behind the `x:key` changes during runtime, the references won't update (static):

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding Model.IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverseConverter}}">
```

The next code snippet again shows how the resource (the converter) is referenced via resource tree lookup by the XAML parser. But this time using the `DynamicResource` markup extension, so that the lookup becomes dynamic. This means the resource will be looked up during runtime. And everytime the resource of the specific `x:Key` changes e.g., a `Brush`, the referencing instance will update accordingly (dynamic):

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding Model.IsReadOnly, Converter={DynamicResource BoolInverseConverter}}">
```

Another code snippet shows how to reference an instance, which is not a resource, but a `static` property defined in the `Converters` class, using the `x:static` markup extension:

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding Model.IsReadOnly, Converter={x:Static Converters.BoolInverseConverter}}">
```

The last code snippet shows another use case of the `x:Static` markup extension. This time it's used to reference an enumeration value (`enum`) and sets the `Visibility` property to a value of the `Visibility` enumeration:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}">
```